# How to discover all Entity Types? One of each?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I need to write a service that connects to CRM, and returns with a list of all of the entity available on the server (custom or otherwise).

How can I do this?  To be clear, I am *not* looking to return all data for all entities.  Just a list of every type, regardless of whether any actually exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `RetrieveAllEntitiesRequest`

```cs
RetrieveAllEntitiesRequest request = new RetrieveAllEntitiesRequest()
{
    EntityFilters = EntityFilters.Entity,
    RetrieveAsIfPublished = true
};

// service is the IOrganizationService
RetrieveAllEntitiesResponse response = (RetrieveAllEntitiesResponse)service.Execute(request);

foreach (EntityMetadata currentEntity in response.EntityMetadata)
{
    string logicalName = currentEntity.LogicalName;
    // your logic here
}
```

note that you will get also system or hidden entities, like `wizardpage` or `recordcountsnapshot`

Comment: This is exactly what I ended up doing!

Answer (score 1):

You will probably find these sections of the MSDN useful:

- [Customize Entity Metadata](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328452.aspx) (lookout for the samples linked on that page).
- [Retrieve and Detect Changes to Metadata](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj863599.aspx).